# General security: Can my database be accessed through my website?

Tags: security

Here's my basic setup...

I have a website that will be used for employees to log in, and submit things like timesheet forms, purchases, etc. The website is written with some basic HTML and then has some PHP on the backend to run some SQL queries to pull/send some information to/from a Microsoft Access Database being hosted on the same server as the website.

My question is this... if somebody got an employees password to log onto the site, how easy would it be for them to view the contents of my database? I honestly have no intuition or clues to guide me here, so I'm asking for some help. Currently set up there is really no protection going on here, so if it is quite easy to access the database, I would like some pointers on how to secure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if somebody got an employees password to log onto the site, how easy
>   would it be for them to view the contents of my database?

That all depends on the permissions and the connection strings.  The same risk applies to the above scenario as what I posted below, but having valid credentials can certainly make it ***easier*** to get at the database.

Even if they didn't get someone's password, it's possible for someone to access your database if the website is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

There are far too many variables to fully cover securing your database on this forum. But here are a few good places to start.

- [General overview of SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) (one of the things you'll be up against.)
- [OWASP Top 10 vulnerabilities list of 2010](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main) (They update every few years, and the OWASP site is a must-read for security info)
- [IBM's recommendations for secure PHP coding](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-secure-apps/index.html).

Finally, ***I know you said you're using PHP, not ASP.NET*** but I'm going to suggest the following link anyway.  It goes way beyond just code, including threat modeling, common risks, etc.  It is an excellent resource even if you're not a .NET developer.

- [Building Secure ASP.NET Applications: Authentication, Authorization, and Secure Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649211.aspx)

Comment: There actually is some basic protection against injections, I am working with somebody to build this website and he included some 'stripslashes' and 'mysql_real_escape_string' commands in the PHP backend, I'm not sure how effective/extensive this is, but I'm assuming it isn't much.

Comment: No problem.  None of those are quick and easy reads, but then again, properly securing/coding a website isn't an easy task, either.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The first question you should ask yourself is if user has any possibility to affect SQL query you send to DB. This is the most dangerous situation.

Comment: As far as just normal interface with the website there is no way to affect the queries aside from just the data they are inputting that is being sent, but I'm not sure what ability somebody trying to hack into/attack the website would have, since I have no knowledge of that field.